# Migration of struts 1.3 to spring with custom tags - Help needed

Tags: java, spring, migration, struts-1, custom-tags

We have a legacy application running on struts 1.3 which needs to be migrated to spring.
This migration is to mitigate security vulnerabilities existing in struts framework. Application contains 1000+ JSP pages which extensively
using custom tags.
There are over 50+ custom tags and these tags extend struts tag library in a hierarchical manner.
Scope of the project is migration from struts to spring.

There are 2 approaches we considered here.

1) Rewrite the custom tag classes which extends struts tag class and replace it with spring alternative classes. 
This approach seems to be complex and time consuming based on the existing custom tag implementation.

2) Keep the existing custom tags and work-flow is redirected using spring(MVC part)
We tried this approach. Even though the work-flow flows through spring, the custom tags used in JSP will not render if we comment the corresponding 
struts action details from struts config. In effect we need to keep both struts and spring setup for the application to work.

Will this(second) approach reduce struts security issues ?

or is there any better approach to consider ?

Comment: This is more an oil and water problem than an oranges and apples problem.  I can't imagine a way to keep struts without keeping all its security problems.   These tags sound like an absolute nightmare.  A wonderful example of why you don't want to write your own framework.  I think your only possibility is to recode the presentation portion.  You should spend some time and look at other frameworks: tiles, thymeleaf, even Struts 2, etc.  There is no reason to use stone knives.  But this is going to be painful regardless.

Comment: If you're keeping the S1 tags then you're not gaining much since they're strongly tied to the rest of the framework. It's almost always best to separate your logic from the framework logic; this is one reason why.